# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, decode

How can I get data from a UTF-8-encoded MySQL database without getting the UnicodeDecodeError? I'm making a website using Python and HTML templates. Here's the code I used to get stuff from the database, which seemed to work fine before I switched the database's encoding to UTF-8:

```
@app.route("/songs")
def content_database_song():
  c = connect_db()
  c.execute("
  SELECT * FROM Tracks
  JOIN Artists USING (ArtistID)
  JOIN Albums USING (AlbumID)
  JOIN Songs USING (SongID)
  ORDER BY UPPER(SoName), UPPER(AlTitle)
  ")
  songslist = []
  rows = c.fetchall()
  for row in rows:
    songslist.append(row)
  return render_template("/song-index.html", songslist = songslist)
```

Here's the complete traceback:

```
UnicodeDecodeError
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

### Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1306, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1294, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1062, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1060, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1047, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/samuelbradshaw/Sites/praises/index.py", line 59, in content_database_song
return render_template("/song-index.html", songslist = songslist)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/templating.py", line 121, in render_template
context, ctx.app)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/templating.py", line 105, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/Users/samuelbradshaw/Sites/praises/templates/song-index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "database-nav.html" %}
File "/Users/samuelbradshaw/Sites/praises/templates/database-nav.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "layout.html" %}
File "/Users/samuelbradshaw/Sites/praises/templates/layout.html", line 26, in top-level template code
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
File "/Users/samuelbradshaw/Sites/praises/templates/database-nav.html", line 13, in block "content"
{% block subcontent %}
File "/Users/samuelbradshaw/Sites/praises/templates/song-index.html", line 47, in block "subcontent"
<strong>Related Scriptures:</strong> {% if song.SoRelatedScriptures != "" %}{{song.SoRelatedScriptures}}{% else %}None{% endif %}<br>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/_markupsafe/_native.py", line 21, in escape
return Markup(unicode(s)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Post the whole traceback, please. That will at least give us some idea *where* you're getting that error.

Comment: My guess is that you should switch back from UTF-8.  Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873556/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x96-in-python

Comment: If the first byte that `guff.decode('ascii')` complains about is 0x96, then `guff` is **not** encoded in UTF-8 -- 0x96 is NOT a valid UTF-8 start byte. I'd suggest inserting `print repr(row)` inside that `for` loop so that we can see exactly what you've got, instead of guessing. What was the database's encoding before you switched it to UTF-8? Did you reload all your text data after the switch?

Comment: It was latin1 before I switched it to UTF-8. I had to switch it because it wouldn't let me put in certain punctuation marks (like the curly single quote and dashes).

Comment: You should not only switch but *convert* the database to UTF-8. I usually did backup, export to sql, create a new in UTF-8, import, rename both new and old, verify some time, drop the old.

Comment: I put `print repr(row)` in and it printed my table. All of the n-dashes show up as `\x96`, and the curly apostrophes as `\x92`. I assume all I need is a simple `decode` statement, but I've never used it and I'm not sure where to put it :) i.e. do I put it in my template, or do I put it in the `for` loop, or in the `return` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to tweak one part of the code – it was in the `connect_db()` method referenced in the code snippet posted above. I changed this:

```
def connect_db():
  global conn
  conn = mdb.connect(dbinfo.server, dbinfo.username, dbinfo.password, dbinfo.database)
  return conn.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

to this:

```
def connect_db():
  global conn
  conn = mdb.connect(dbinfo.server, dbinfo.username, dbinfo.password, dbinfo.database, charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
  return conn.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Note the `charset='utf8', use_unicode=True` when connecting. That's all I had to change after switching my database to Unicode! :)