# Using Beautiful Soup with accents and different characters

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, python-2.7

I'm using Beautiful Soup to pull medal winners from past Olympics. It's tripping over the use of accents in some of the events and athlete names. I've seen similar problems posted online but I'm new to Python and having trouble applying them to my code.

If I print my soup, the accents appear fine. but when I start parsing the soup (and write it to a CSV file) the accented characters become garbled. 
'Louis Perrée' becomes 'Louis Perr√©e'

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.databaseolympics.com/sport/sportevent.htm?sp=FEN&enum=130')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

g = open('fencing_medalists.csv','w"')
t = soup.findAll("table", {'class' : 'pt8'})

for table in t:
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        for td in cols:
            theText=str(td.find(text=True))
            #theText=str(td.find(text=True)).encode("utf-8")
            if theText!="None":
                g.write(theText)
            else: 
                g.write("")
            g.write(",")
        g.write("\n")
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried your code, it worded quite well. Did you put  "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @WooParadog: He has no need of a coding declaration; he has no encodied unicode literals in his source code. The coding declaration is for the use of the Python compiler when it is compiling the source code.

Answer (score 4):

If you're dealing with unicode, always treat the response read from disk or network as bag of bytes instead of string.

The text in your CSV file is probably utf-8 encoded, which should be decoded first.

```
import codecs
# ...
content = response.read()
html = codecs.decode(content, 'utf-8')
```

Also you need to encode your unicode text to utf-8 before writing it to output file. Use `codecs.open` to open the output file, specifying encoding. It will transparently handle output encoding for you.

```
g = codecs.open('fencing_medalists.csv', 'wb', encoding='utf-8')
```

and make the following changes to string writing code:

```
    theText = td.find(text=True)
    if theText is not None:
        g.write(unicode(theText))
```

**Edit:** BeautifulSoup probably does [automatic unicode decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7873585/1897), so you could skip the `codecs.decode` on response.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I add the codecs.open and try to encode it as utf-8 it returns the following errors:
  File "scrape_fencing_medalists.py", line 29, in <module>
    g.write(theText)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 691, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You were coercing the extracted text to `str` before writing. codecs module will write `unicode` objects with proper encoding transparently. Updated my answer with the changes you need to make in your script.