# Wrong accented characters using Beautiful Soup in Python on a local HTML file

Tags: python, html, parsing, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm quite familiar with Beautiful Soup in Python, I have always used to scrape live site.

Now I'm scraping a local HTML file ([link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NsYpFwb4zYMTTGZhPhUy9CDiNC0la4_p), in case you want to test the code), the only problem is that accented characters are not represented in the correct way (this never happened to me when scraping live sites).

This is a simplified version of the code

```
import requests, urllib.request, time, unicodedata, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('AH.html'), "html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all('table')
titles = tables[0].find_all('tr')
print(titles[55].text)
```

which prints the following output

`2:22 - Il Destino Ãˆ GiÃ  Scritto (2017 ITA/ENG) [1080p] [BLUWORLD]`

while the correct output should be

`2:22 - Il Destino È Già Scritto (2017 ITA/ENG) [1080p] [BLUWORLD]`

---

I looked for a solution, read many questions/answers and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264937/using-beautiful-soup-with-accents-and-different-characters), which I implemented in the following way

```
import requests, urllib.request, time, unicodedata, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs

response = open('AH.html')
content = response.read()
html = codecs.decode(content, 'utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

However, it runs the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\score.py", line 8, in <module>
    html = codecs.decode(content, 'utf-8')
TypeError: decoding with 'utf-8' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')
```

I guess is easy to solve the problem, but how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open("AH.html") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    tb = soup.find("table")
    for item in tb.find_all("tr")[55]:
        print(item.text)
```

[image]

I've to say, that your first code is actually fine and should works.

Regarding the second code, you are trying to `decode` `str` which is faulty. as `decode` function is for `byte` `object`.

I believe that you are using `Windows` where the default encoding of it is `cp1252` not `UTF-8`.

Could you please run the following code:

```py
import sys

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(sys.stdin.encoding)
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(sys.stderr.encoding)
```

And check your output if it's `UTF-8` or `cp1252`.

> note that if you are using `VSCode` with `Code-Runner`, kindly run your code in the terminal as `py code.py`

### SOLUTIONS (from the chat)

(1) If you are on windows 10

- Open Control Panel and change view by Small icons
- Click Region
- Click the Administrative tab
- Click on Change system locale...
- Tick the box "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8..."
- Click OK and restart your pc

(2) If you are not on Windows 10 or just don't want to change the previous setting, then in the first code change `open("AH.html")` to `open("AH.html", encoding="UTF-8")`, that is write:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("AH.html", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    tb = soup.find("table")
    for item in tb.find_all("tr")[55]:
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, however I get the same wrong output as you can see from here https://i.imgur.com/aH69dHM.png I guess the problem is my computer?

Comment: @soundwave well, check with `with open("AH.html", encoding="utf-8") as f:`

Comment: @soundwave I noticed that you have did faulty thing !! please and please. run your code outside Python interpreter !! for the `import sys` code . put it in a file and then run it as `py code.py`

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean? If I run `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` and others commands outside Python I get errors. I saved the code that you wrote at the beginning of the answer, inside a file called score2.py, but when in the cmd I run both `score2.py` or `py score2.py` I got the wrong output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209860/discussion-between--c-and-sound-wave).

Answer (score 2):

Using `open('AH.html')` decodes the file using a default encoding that may not be the encoding of the file.  `BeautifulSoup` understands the HTML headers, specifically the following content indicates the file is UTF-8-encoded:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Open the file in binary mode and let `BeautifulSoup` figure it out:

```
with open("AH.html","rb") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
```

Sometimes, websites set the encoding incorrectly.  In that case you can specify the encoding yourself if you know what it should be.

```
with open("AH.html",encoding='utf8') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thanks, anyway the last code that you wrote, which solves the problem, was already written by αԋɱҽԃ in the chat (see comments to its answer). But he went even further, and he was able to find the origin of the problem: UTF-8 was not enabled for programs that don't support Unicode (I'm on windows 10). By enabling it, the command `encoding="utf8"` was no more needed, i.e. the command `open("AH.html")` does the job.

Comment: @soundwave Answers in chat aren’t answers for StackOverfow questions. Changing Windows setting isn’t best answer. Using BeautifulSoup correctly is. also, explicitly specifying the encoding instead of relying on defaults that vary by OS version is a better practice as well.

Comment: I added to the question the 2 working solutions which are in the chat

Comment: @soundwave Answers on StackOverflow should be in the answers section so they can be voted on.  Since you've awarded an answer, edit that one so it is actually correct or if not comfortable with that, write your own answer and award it to yourself. But in my opinion having to change Windows settings isn't the correct answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited the answer adding the two solutions. Thanks.