# Another BeautifulSoup error 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm hoping to scrape data from the table for passengers going through TSA security lines, but I keep getting this error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2713' in position 33780: character maps to <undefined>
```

from this code

```
url = "https://www.tsa.gov/coronavirus/passenger-throughput"
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features = 'lxml')
text = soup.get_text()
soup.prettify()

print(soup)
```

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @snakecharmerb 100% he's using a windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well let me explain for you what happened actually.

Read the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2713' in position 33780: character maps to <undefined>
```

Now from my side if ran the following:

```py
print("\u2713")
```

Output will be the following `Unicode`:

```
✓
```

I believe that you are using Windows where the default encoding of it is `cp1252` not `UTF-8`.

You can verify that using the following:

```py
import sys

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(sys.stdin.encoding)
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(sys.stderr.encoding)
```

Or directly via `cmd` by running the following command: `chcp`

Now you can change the system encoding by opening `cmd` and run the following cmd:

```
cp 65001
```

Check the [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) doc.

```
Identifier  .NET Name   Additional information
65001       utf-8       Unicode (UTF-8)
```

> note that if you are using `VSCode` with `Code-Runner`, kindly run your code in the terminal as `py code.py` or change append the following setting:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && python"
    }
}
```

Check my previous answer for similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741827/wrong-accented-characters-using-beautiful-soup-in-python-on-a-local-html-file/60742176#60742176)