# bytes to str conversion failure in python3

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

The code is self-explained...

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib.request as req
>>> url = 'http://bangladeshbrands.com/342560550782-44083.html'
>>> res = req.urlopen(url)
>>> html = res.read() 
>>> type(html)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> html = html.decode('utf-8') # bytes -> str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 66081: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Why are you not using a module that knows how to handle HTML via HTTP properly in the first place?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, could you explain? The read() method is working properly for most of the urls.

Comment: The `read()` method doesn't give you any information about what the server is telling you the charset of the HTML is.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Can you suggest any alternative solution?

Comment: Other than using a module that knows what it's doing?

Comment: Can *urllib* handle that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873556/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x96-in-python

Comment: What `res.headers.get_content_charset()` returns?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian 'utf-8'

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some bad unicode characters in the information you get from the url so some kind of error handling is needed.  Why not use requests, a "HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings." and let it handle the details:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 15 2014, 22:01:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://bangladeshbrands.com/342560550782-44083.html'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> html_as_text = r.text
>>> print(html_as_text[66070:66090])
ml">Toddler�s items<
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The html page might have [inconsistent encodings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#inconsistent-encodings). Content-type HTTP header (`res.headers.get_content_charset()`) says it is `'utf-8'`. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` inside the html document confirms it. But `html.decode('utf-8')` fails.

It seems the issue is with the smart quote [`"’"` (U + 2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK)](http://codepoints.net/U+2019). It is encoded using `cp1252` encoding `b'\x92'` (the byte from the `UnicodeDecodeError` message). To fix it, you could use [`UnicodeDammit.detwingle()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#inconsistent-encodings):

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

text = UnicodeDammit.detwingle(html).decode('utf-8')
```

Though for this particular document, `html.decode('cp1252')` produces the same result i.e., it might be just the wrong character encoding specification by the http server and the html authoring tool.