# How to solve python 'utf-8' error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file of 6GB in my python 3 terminal and was not able to execute the read file line. the code is as below:

```
#define data directory

data_dir = 'C://Star/star_data/csv\Globe'

#read the review dataset
yelp = pd.read_csv(data_dir+'\star_data_python.csv')
X, y = star.data, star.target
X.shape
```

error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-bc09b45c73bb> in <module>()
      4 
      5 #read the review dataset
----> 6 yelp = pd.read_csv(data_dir+'\star_data_python.csv')
      7 X, y = star.data, star.target
      8 X.shape
```

What could be the problem? thanks

Comment: You are using both `/` and `\ `  in your path... if you are using windows please use only `/` with `r` in front on your string e.g `data_dir = r'C://Star/star_data/csv/Globe'`

Comment: If not a path issue, try to add `,encoding='utf-8'` to read_csv

Comment: #define data directory
I have corrected it to the line below but i am still getting the same error. 
data_dir = r'C://Star/star_data/csv/Globe'

#read the review dataset
yelp = pd.read_csv(data_dir + '/star_data_python.csv')

Comment: Hi @MugB, try to add encoding utf-8 to your csv file: `pd.read_csv(data_dir+'\star_data_python.csv, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:6086)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas\parser.c:9266)()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 2543: invalid continuation byte

Comment: i am still getting the error, i wonder if it is due to the file size, it has about 30, 000 dimensions

Comment: `pd.read_csv(data_dir+'\star_data_python.csv, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')`, or try to find the right encoding of your file :) This is **not** a size problem.

Comment: seems to be suggesting for me to create some kind of parser. ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-e6e193157a7c> in <module>()
      4 
      5 #read the review dataset
----> 6 yelp = pd.read_csv(data_dir+'\star_data_python.csv', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')

TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'

Comment: pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10415)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10691)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:11437)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:11308)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:27037)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Comment: I'm sorry read_csv doesnt have an `errors` argument, please see my link do check all optional arguments in my answer.

Comment: thanks Max, i will try.

Comment: good job :) which encoding did you use at the end?

Comment: it worked with ISO but still had memory issues trying to process the data

Comment: Ok, you may need to cut your file in several chunks if possible. I run into a similar issue a year ago and decided to create a file to keep indinces of chunks over a big file. The plus size is that you may be able to use multithread. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the idea Max. as much as possible i didnt want to manipulate the raw file as I noticed when i attempt to do that, it gets saved incorrectly. lots more to learn on how best to deal with huge files like this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `r` before your path since you are on Windows:

e.g

```
data_dir = r'C://Star/star_data/csv/Globe'
```

The `'r'` means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored.

Try calling [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `encoding='latin1'`, `encoding='iso-8859-1'` or `encoding='cp1252'`; these the various encodings found on Windows.

e.g

```
full_path = data_dir + r'/star_data_python.csv'
pd.read_csv(full_path, encoding='latin1')
```

List of helpful SO answers:

- [About 'r'
  string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)
- [About encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462807/encoding-error-in-panda-read-csv)