# Error message in Jupyter as "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3"

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding

I am getting following error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `read_csv` with `encoding='latin1'`, `encoding='iso-8859-1'` or `encoding='cp1252'`

Source : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462807/encoding-error-in-panda-read-csv)