# Read Excel with data in Hindi in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new to Python Pandas and working on a small application where in i want to read my excel file having data in Hindi Language.

Issue I am facing is , pandas is not able to read hindi words and is placing some arbitary '?' symbol.

I have tried adding encoding to utf-8 but that is also not working.

My Excel Data :

[image]

Python Code :

```
df = pd.read_csv("Vegaretable_List.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

Output :

```
['?? ' '??? ' '???? ' '????? ' '????']
```

Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to find out the encoding of your input file. It may be something else. You can also use this tool: https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: you require language converter like codec. https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html refer this link

Comment: Try opening the file and save as `CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem shouldn't occur if the file is read in using the same encoding it was created with.

If you get `"???"`, it means the csv or excel file was saved with a different encoding.

Here is a table of the [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Also, you could open your file in an appropriate program, and save it with `UTF-8`, in order to read with your code.

#### Also See:

- [SO: Encoding Error in Panda read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30462807/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

Do not create csv file, instead use excel file in `.xlsx` format. Python will read the hindi text. I did this and it worked.

```py
dataset = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
```

Here the `Data.xlsx` contains all the hindi text that you gave.

Best of luck

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your Excel/CSV file has a content similar to this:

```
मिशल
बहादुर
मेरी
जेन
जॉन
स्मिथ
```

The encoding type is correct. It's just that you have to iterate through the data to get it back.

**For .CSV**

```
import csv

with open('customers.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

**For .XLSX**

```
with open('customers.xlsx', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for row in data:
        print(row.strip())
```