# UnicodeDecodeError while generating tfrecords

Tags: python, tensorflow, encoding, object-detection-api, tfrecord

I am trying to generate tfrecords for png images and csv labels for training an object detection model using tensorflow API for detecting objects. I'm working with a script from a tutorial but I get this error  : **`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 65: invalid continuation byte`**
which I dont know how to solve it. Do you guys have any idea ??

Here's the program to generate tfrecords :

```
"""
Usage:
  # From tensorflow/models/
  # Create train data:
  python preprocessing/csv_to_tfrecords.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv  --output_path=data/train.record
  # Create test data:
  python preprocessing/csv_to_tfrecords.py --csv_input=data/test_labels.csv  --output_path=data/test.record
  
"""
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

flags = tf.compat.v1.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'capsule':
        return 1
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_png = fid.read()
    encoded_png_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_png)
    image = Image.open(encoded_png_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'png'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_png),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.compat.v1.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

After trying to generate the tfrecords I've got as a traceback :

```
python preprocessing/csv_to_tfrecords.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv  --output_path=data/train.record
2021-05-31 21:34:20.376813: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-05-31 21:34:20.377348: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessing/csv_to_tfrecords.py", line 100, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "preprocessing/csv_to_tfrecords.py", line 91, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "preprocessing/csv_to_tfrecords.py", line 46, in create_tf_example
    encoded_png = fid.read()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 117, in read     
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.path_to_str(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 65: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback to the question so we can see the fail. Also, can you shorten this to some smaller example that fails the same way? It seems kinda like you just posted the tutorial itself without trying to widdle this problem down first.

Comment: @tdelaney I edited the question below you can check

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with `pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)` line. Try using different `encoding` schemes while the csv file. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30470630/15431423).