# Visual Studio (Python) Unicode Decode Error x

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, decode, codec

I am trying to run a code on a friend's PC. The same code runs perfectly fine on my PC. But, is generating the following error on my friend's PC:

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 2523: invalid continuation byte
File "C:\Users\t848451\Desktop\Phone and User Report\Phone_User_Report_Macro (1).py", line 6, in 
df_phone=pd.read_csv("Phone_Report.csv", engine='python')

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import re as re
import calendar
import datetime

df_phone=pd.read_csv("Phone_Report.csv")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also tried:   pd.read_csv("Phone_Report.csv")

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Are you sure that the file is encoded in UTF-8?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should not add any images in here.
Anyway try to add `encoding="UTF-8"` in the parameter of `pd.read_csv`. or try some other encodings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I have updated my question. Is there a reason why this needs to be added in my coworker's version but not mine?

Comment: I am not an expert but I think different os use different encodings for various purposes and sometimes you just need to explicitly set the parameter for compatibility. [List of Python standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: I changed my code to: df_phone=pd.read_csv('Phone_Report.csv', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: But I am still getting the same error

Comment: then try some other encodings. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30470630/13193861) might help.