# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 227: invalid start byte

Tags: css, django

I am starting with **Django**.

I've got an error but cannot sort it out. Does anyone know why I am getting this?

I am doing an `{% extends "base.html" %}` on my login page.

I get this error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and i solve when i replace special character like `à` with his equivalent in web format `&#224;` or `&agrave;`

I think has default when django take your `file.html` for render, he don't manage specials characters during the render process but if you create a variable in your views.py and you send it to your template it's can work.

So you have 2 solutions :

- replace specials characters in template with [equivalent in web](https://www.wired.com/2010/02/special_characters/)
- send a variable with your special character/word to your tamplate.

EDIT:

- An other guy have the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873556/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x96-in-python), it's the encoded the your web page (bad character), the recommendation is using BeautifulSoup. I solve it whitout, maybe you can do it too.

Comment: I've checked my html but there is special character like à. I've removed the é to be sure that is not causing any issue.

Comment: Can need see the page.html ? And you have the position of the bad character : `position 226` now you just need to count and find it :)

Comment: I want to resolve it without adding components if I can:

Comment: See your error => Unicode error hint : `coop ? {% b` where `?` is your bad character. So try to replace is by something different or remove it (it's can be no ASCII character).

Comment: Thank you, I found out that there was a "-" I removed it and it's working now;